# When does Facebook return JSON and when does it return plain text

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I noticed that sometimes Facebook returns JSON data (like for all error messages and for user data), but other times it returns a plain text string (like when returning an access token).

Is there any general logic to when Facebook returns JSON and when it returns plain text?

Comment: I think that access tokens are returned as plain text might be owed to the OAuth 2.0 specification …

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any general logic behind this. Something that can help you tough is the `Content-Type` from the header in the response.

Example:

```
...
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 154
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
...
```

This way you can tell your software how to react for each Content-Type. Either it's `text/plain` or `application/json`.

Hope it helps

-Laurent